# How to enable a button in a delphi form only if all combo boxes have the selection made

Tags: combobox, selection

Need to check if multiple Combo boxes are not empty.
Tried for one combo box, how to apply the same to multiple.

```
if (combobox1.ItemIndex <> -1) then
  begin
     btnOK.Enabled := true;
  end
else
btnOK.Enabled := false;
```

PS: I'm new to delphi please bear with mistakes, if any.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest would be a construct like this

```
if (ComboBox1.ItemIndex = -1) or (ComboBox2.ItemIndex = -1) or (ComboBox3.ItemIndex = -1) then
    Exit;

Button1.Enabled := true;
```

This exits the procedure if any of the comboboxes has -1 selected. If all boxes are selected, the button gets enabled.

Or you could just bind them all together and write directly to the Enabled property

```
Button1.Enabled := (ComboBox1.ItemIndex <> -1) and (ComboBox2.ItemIndex <> -1) and (ComboBox3.ItemIndex <> -1);
```

The most beautiful way, if you really have a lot of comboboxes is using arrays

```
procedure TForm1.SetButtonActive;
var
    boxes: array of TComboBox;
    box: TComboBox;
begin
    boxes := [ComboBox1, ComboBox2, ComboBox3];

    for box in boxes do
        if box.ItemIndex = -1 then
            Exit;

    Button1.Enabled := true;
end;
```